# nginx proxy into Tomcat (not ROOT) application

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, proxy

I got a problem with proxing my connection with nginx. Here is the situation: I got Tomcat running on `localhost:8080`, which is fine and set up. On that tomcat, I have 2 applications running at paths `/app-test` and `/app-prod` respectively.

I have 2 subdomains, say `test.mydomain.com` and `prod.mydomain.com` and I want those subdomains to be proxied to respective tomcat applications. In other words, when my user types: `test.mydomain.com/some/resource` I want that request to be proxied to `localhost:8080/app-test/some/resource` etc. This should work just fine according to tutorials, however it doesn't.

For example, when I go to `test.mydomain.com`, it redirects me to `test.mydomain.com/app-test/login` which gets `404` (Note that there is a spring application, that redirects to `/login` URI). The desired behavior here is to redirect me to `test.mydomain.com/login`. How can I accomplish this? I found this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/763259/nginx-reverse-proxy-to-tomcat), but that seems to be hacky and not very elegant.

What I got so far in my conf:

```
upstream tomcat_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  prod.mydomain.com;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_connect_timeout      240;
        proxy_send_timeout         240;
        proxy_read_timeout         240;
        # note, there is not SSL here! plain HTTP is used
        proxy_pass http://tomcat_server/app-prod/;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate ...
    ssl_certificate_key ...

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  test.mydomain.com;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_connect_timeout      240;
        proxy_send_timeout         240;
        proxy_read_timeout         240;
        # note, there is not SSL here! plain HTTP is used
        proxy_pass http://tomcat_server/app-test/;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate ...
    ssl_certificate_key ...
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}
```

So, my question is whether there is more elegant solution that one from serverfault thread. Thanks for any ideas!

**EDIT:** The problem with the rewrite solution is that it allows users to see the internal structure of my stack, I mean, it redirects them to `test.mydomain.com/app-test/...`, which I think may be a security risk.

Comment: Have you considered using virtual hosts in tomcat itself?

Comment: Hi, no, I didn't, because I did not wanted to setup my routing on two places. Moreover, I decided for nginx because of the simplicity it provides when configuring https. Anyway, what do you mean, by virtual hosts in Tomcat? separate contexts? Because, I have context paths handled by SpringMVC.

Comment: Tomcat's virtual hosts are analogous to nginx's `server`s. Applications are bound to virtual hosts and served based on the value of the host header. With that, you could have multiple applications deployed to the root (`/`) context. All you would then have to do is make sure that nginx forwards the Host header from clients (or set an arbitrary one that you can choose)

Comment: That's interesting, thank you. I'm gonna have a look at that. However, I'd still refer some nginx solution, I got my deployment kinda automated (using `tomcat-maven-plugin`) and I am not sure that it can handle virtual hosts. Gonna check that out.

Comment: In the apache docs, I read some time ago, that one should not use `/` as context path for the application. This makes me still want to do this in some way on nginx.